# Does java have a Util that creates a delimited string from a list that wraps each value in some char?

Tags: java

For example I have a list of:

```
new LinkedList<String>{{
    add("a");
    add("b");
    add("c");
}}
```

Is there a util that turns the above into this string:

```
~a~,~b~,~c~
```

I want to create a comma separated list but with the values surrounded by another character I choose. I can create a for statement that does a string append on the list, but I want to avoid that if there is already a util out there.

Comment: Wish people who were down voting would provide the OP a reason why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could use [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

```
String output = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("~,~", "~", "~"));
```

It uses a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) behind the scenes, a new class that has been introduced.

Otherwise, pre-java 8 and if you don't want a third-party library, a `StringBuilder` with a for loop will do the trick.

Comment: Still woouldn't know why this would be required, but valid answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the list to an array, then use the StringUtils.join() method:

```
List<String> items = new LinkedList<String>();
items.add("a");
items.add("b");
items.add("c");

String[] arr = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
String delimited = "~" + StringUtils.join(arr, "~,~") + "~";
```

You'll need the first and last "~" to be added separately, as shown in the last line.

This method doesn't require Java 8, in case you haven't upgraded yet.